# Fast Report export by mail using Gmail smtp

Tags: delphi, smtp, fastreport

I'm using Fast Report 5 and Rad Studio Seattle and trying to send report via gmail smtp host by using Fast Report's mail export object. when i try either of the ports (465 and 587) i get an error "530. 5.7.0 must issue a STARTTLS command first". If i use a different smtp server with different settings, the report is mailed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP TfrxMailExport doesn't supports SSL. Use TfrxMailExport with MAPI or MSOutlook option (mail client should be installed, configured and runned)

Comment: Thank you for such a fast reply. So if I use MAPI with gmail's settings, i should be able to send the report from gmail? I'll play around and see what i can do. Or do you suggest i should use a different provider entirely?

Comment: MAPI typically cannot access Gmail. MAPI is primarily used for accessing MSExchange, or at least invoking a MAPI-enabled client like Outlook to delegate emails through their own settings. You would have to write/find a MAPI provider that knows how to talk to Gmail SMTP/IMAP with SSL/TLS enabled. Or configure Outlook to access Gmail, and then use MAPI to invoke Outlook. If FastReport does not support SSL/TLS then it cannot send using Gmail directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may uncomment {$DEFINE USE_INDY} in the frx.inc and recompile FR with Indy support

```
//-------------------Use INDY for e-mail export ---------------------
//{$DEFINE USE_INDY}
//----------- Use INDY 9 instead of 10 for save filters -------------
// comment these lines if you have indy 10 on Delphi 7
//{$IFDEF USE_INDY}
```